# How to add GeoServer Vector tiles in React using OpenLayers API?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, mapbox, vector-tiles, react

We are creating a React application and we want to display vector tile layers from GeoServer. The basemap is required from ArcGIS REST service using the following code and it works properly

```
const basemap = new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        attributions: 'Tiles © <a href="https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
            'rest/services/Canvas/World_Dark_Gray_Reference/MapServer">ArcGIS</a>',
        url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
            'Canvas/World_Dark_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
      })
    });
```

As for the vector tile layers, we use Mapbox Vector Tiles (MVT) and the code is shown as the following but it did not work.

```
    const initialStateSource = new VectorTileSource({
      url: 'https://smartcommunityhealth.ahc.umn.edu/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/SOLAP%3Aus_states_simplified@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf',
      format: new MVT(),
    });

    const initialStateLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
      visible: statesVisible,
      source: initialStateSource,
      style: geoOutline
    });
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: The clue is tms where the y tile coordinates start at the bottom left instead of the normal top left in xyz sources.  OpenLayeers will handle that if you use `{-y}` as a placeholder in the url https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-info-forked-hi8w0